# Use class from older API level removed in newer API level

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to access the `android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic` class on API level 16 but compile my application for API level 19. The `WebSettingsClassic` class has been removed in API level 19 and thus the compiler cannot see it. How do I solve this?

Comment: are you sure? Do you have any documentation stating that the class was removed from the public API?

Comment: :) This class has not been removed since API 19. Check error properly..

Comment: in that case you can copy that class to your own app and use it :)

Comment: That class is not removed in API 19 . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Comment: `WebSettingsClassic` has been removed from the source code completely in 4.4. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/webkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using the following modified code. This allows you to compile against API level 19.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public static String getUserAgent(final Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(context);
    }
    else {
        try {
            final Class<?> webSettingsClassicClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic");
            final Constructor<?> constructor = webSettingsClassicClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class, Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewClassic"));
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            final Method method = webSettingsClassicClass.getMethod("getUserAgentString");
            return (String) method.invoke(constructor.newInstance(context, null));
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            return new WebView(context).getSettings()
                    .getUserAgentString();
        }
    }
}
```